# How can I fix pip install error: 'EnvironmentError: [Errno 42] Illegal byte sequence'?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, kivy

I am trying to download `kivy` module using `pip`.

When I run the `pip install command`, I got an error: `Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 42] Illegal byte sequence.`

I already re-installed `python`, I am running as an administrator and I also tried to download via the wheel file. All of the above causes the same environment error.

Comment: Please check python path is added in environment variable or not.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5665

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in pip https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5665.
The current workaround is to run the command in silent mode

```
pip install kivy -q
```

or

```
pip install kivy --progress-bar=off
```

Comment: If you really want the progress bar, this also works: chcp 1255

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install kivy -q
```

(Not a solution, a workaround - This is a bug in displaying progress bar in pip. Above command hides the progress bar while installing)

Solution based on [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5665#issuecomment-421727702).