# ImportError: cannot import name _overlapped

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to start a test case via cmd . 
The framework I am using for building the test cases is robot framework coded with Python. and when I initiate the test by inserting the command line I get the following :

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Jenkins\workspace\Robot\EMS_Automation\RobotSuits\runner_test_HReqMod_Blocking.robot': Importing test library 'C:\Jenkins\workspace\Robot\EMS_Automation\Modules\EMS_Tests\HReqModTests.py' failed: ImportError: cannot import name _overlapped
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Jenkins\workspace\Robot\EMS_Automation\Modules\EMS_Tests\HReqModTests.py", line 8, in <module>
    from EMS_Handlers.FileHandler import FileHandler
  File "C:\Jenkins\workspace\Robot\EMS_Automation\Modules\EMS_Handlers\FileHandler.py", line 15, in <module>
    from EMS_Handlers.RequestsHandler import RequestsHandler
  File "C:\Jenkins\workspace\Robot\EMS_Automation\Modules\EMS_Handlers\RequestsHandler.py", line 7, in <module>
    import requests,pyshark,socket
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyshark\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyshark.capture.live_capture import LiveCapture
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyshark\capture\live_capture.py", line 3, in <module>
    import trollius as asyncio
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\trollius\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import selectors  # Will also be exported.
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\trollius\selectors.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .py33_exceptions import wrap_error, InterruptedError
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\trollius\py33_exceptions.py", line 83, in <module>
    from trollius import _overlapped
```

what is the cause and the solution for this problem? 
I am using python 2.7.17 ; robotframework 3.1.2

Comment: Is `_overlapped` part of `robotframework 3.1.2`?

Comment: How can I make sure of that?

Comment: I just installed `robotframework` but I got `ImportError: No module named trollius`.

Comment: I think you may have `setup.py` to handle this?

Comment: Should I run "pip install ." in cmd?

Comment: If you have the file. Share us the list of files in your directory.

Comment: I just realized I do not have setup.py file.
which directory you mean?

Comment: Aren't you using https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework? There is `setup.py` under the project root. `python setup.py install` is usual way to start... usually...

Comment: No I am not using this repository . also 'python setup.py install' does not work

Comment: Right, you installed the package on your system, which is not recommended way to go. I think it is worth to give a try: start by cloning the repository.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204036/discussion-between-gyuhyeon-choi-and-elias-shourosh).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to install the module

```
pip install trollius
```

And import it in Python

```
import trollius
```

Then, in general, make use of `help(trollius)` cmd in Python to retrieve info about the module. As you suggest, check for correctness of the library version being used.

If it doens't work then maybe it's deprecated?

[image]

Comment: I tested it but I still got `ImportError: cannot import name _overlapped`. What is `_overlapped`...?

Comment: trollius is installed in my system , the version is 1.0.4

Comment: You have to type it into Python

Comment: I got the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'trollius' is not defined

Comment: Open a fresh terminal. Type pip install trollius. Then open python by typing python in terminal. Now type import trollius. It should be fine. If it doesn't work make sure you do not have multiple version of python and pip, e.g pip/python and pip3/python3

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to upgrade your trollius installation. Run below command

```
python -m pip install trollius==2.2.post1
```

After this you should see a file _overlapped.pyd(responsible for the error mentioned) under ..Lib\site-packages\trollius folder.

If present, you will not observe this import error anymore.

Comment: This is what I get. So it has something to do with the installer of Python (64 bit or 32)

|ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 42] Illegal byte sequence

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53985263/how-can-i-fix-pip-install-error-environmenterror-errno-42-illegal-byte-sequ