# No module named '_overlapped'

Tags: python, django, terminal

Working on a masters project and a fellow course mate has developed a web application using Django on a windows computer and has sent the file to us. I am trying to run the server on my MacBook terminal but when I run it, get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_overlapped'. I have installed trollius as recommended in a previous post but hasn't worked for me. any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59281626/importerror-cannot-import-name-overlapped

Answer (score 18):

I got this error when I wanted NULL as default for my Model's field, so **Visual Studio Code** added automatically on the first line `from asyncio.windows_events import NULL`, I saw that the traceback were pointing

> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/windows_events.py", line 3, in `<module>`
> import _overlapped

---

So I just deleted `from asyncio.windows_events import NULL`, then the error was gone.