# Pymongo windows download

Tags: python, mongodb, pip, anaconda, pymongo

I have python version 3.6.8 downloaded on my windows computer, and I generally use jupyter notebook as my IDE through anaconda.

I type into the command prompt and/or the windows power shell- pip install pymongo,
and I receive this error.

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting pymongo
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/37/2b47d177f54da9f9662e2ac13f8841089da1d41ff6efe115cc4c3711cf56/pymongo-3.12.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl (393kB)
    2% |Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 42] Illegal byte sequence
```

And I have no idea why, please help.

Comment: You need to point the `jupyter notebook` to the correct version of `python`. Version 2.7  has reached the end of its life.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53985347/7976758 Try `pip install -q pymongo` or `pip install --progress-bar=off pymongo`